# Solve $\tan x =\sqrt{3}$, finding all solutions.

Tags: trigonometry

My attempt so far:

$$
\tan x = \sqrt3
$$

$$
\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}= \sqrt3 
$$

Then I look at the unit circle to find possible solutions. I find two solutions: $$
\frac{\pi}{3} \text{  and }\frac{4\pi}{3}
$$

However, I find the answer to be:
$$
x = \frac{\pi}{3} + \pi k
$$
Why isn't $4\pi/3$ included in the solution?

(edit: I mistakenly wrote $7\pi/6$ instead of $4\pi/3$. Sorry for the confusion.)

Comment: $$\tan\left(r\pi+\frac\pi6\right)=\tan\frac\pi6=\frac1{\sqrt3}$$ Put $r=1$

Comment: @Monica - you know that there are infinitely many solutions, right?

Comment: @Monica, Set $k=1$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Can it really be that simple? I laughed when you pointed that out. Completely clear now. If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it so. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\tan\left(\frac {7\pi}{6}\right) = \dfrac{-\frac 12}{-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}} = \dfrac 1{\sqrt 3}$$

So $x = \dfrac{7\pi}{6}$ does not solve $\tan x = \sqrt 3$.

The second solution $x$ in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ is $$x = \dfrac{4\pi}3$$

ADDED after EDITED post:

Note that $$\dfrac {4\pi}{3} = \frac{\pi}{3} + 1\cdot \pi = \dfrac{\pi}{3} + k\pi, \;k = 1$$

And we can characterize ***all*** solutions $x_i = \pi/3 + k\pi$.

Comment: (Turns out $7\pi / 6$ was a typo.)

Comment: I've expanded my answer after your edit. Your solution of $\dfrac 43 \pi$ is included in the "global" solution $\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ when we add one multiple of $\pi$...that gives us $$\frac \pi 3 + \pi = \dfrac{ \pi + 3\pi}{3} = \dfrac{4\pi}{3}.$$ Every $x = \dfrac{\pi}{3} + k\pi$, where $k$ can take on *any* integer value, is a solution, including when $k = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$tan(x) = \sqrt 3$ is positive in the first and third quadrants.  The principal value for this equation is $\frac {\pi}{3}$; the second value in the third quadrant is $\frac {4 \pi}{3}$ (valid in $0<x<2 \pi$); the general value is $\frac {\pi}{3} + \pi k$.

Answer (score 0):

In the answer, if k=1 you get the solution $ \frac{{4\pi }}{3} $

Comment: "Why isn't 4π/3 included in the solution? ". I thought I was helping to answer this part of the question.

Comment: I know. It's a misclick and this indeed answers the question.

Comment: Are you referring to my choice of answer as a misclick? I chose the more recent one that was a good and full explanation. While this does answer the question, I felt it was a copy of an earlier response and it came later than the first good and complete answer.