# Is there more than one correct way to write the answer to the question; find all solutions for $ \tan(x) = \sqrt3 $

Tags: trigonometry

[Same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714392/solve-tan-x-sqrt3-finding-all-solutions)

Someone already partially asked and answered my question.  I wonder what is the most acceptable way to state the answer to the question, find all solutions to the equation $\tan(x) = \sqrt3$

The book I have says the domain for tan is $ \theta + \frac{\pi}{2}k$. Where k is an even integer.  The other way is $ \theta + \pi k$ where k is an integer.  Is one of these a better answer then the other?

The answer to the equation is either $$ x= \frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{2} k$$ where k is an even integer.  Or,$$ x = \frac{\pi}{3}+\pi k$$ where k is an integer.

Is one of these more acceptable than the other?

Comment: The say the same thing... but for my money, $\frac {pi}{3} + n\pi$ is more to the point.

Comment: I don't think that book domain reference is correct... There's typically $\pi$ between consecutive zeroes of $\cos$... Note that adding $\frac{\pi}2$ to $\theta$ would negate the result when $\tan$ is applied.

Comment: @abiessu The OP says $x= \frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{2} k$ with $k$ **even**, so it's correct

Comment: @jjagmath: ack, the misreading strikes again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention for writing the solution of most trigonometric equations is to have the solution for *all* integers, not restrict them to certain parameters.

Note if you put each of the solutions under a common denominator (the book's answer and the conventional answer), you get the following...

$$\dfrac {2 \pi + 3 \pi k}{6} \qquad (1) $$ and $$\dfrac {\pi + 3 \pi k}{3}\ \qquad (2)$$
For $(1)$ (the book's answer),

- For $k = 0$ we get $\pi \over 3$, which is one of the correct angles.
- For $k=1$ we get $\tan \frac {5 \pi} {6} = -\frac {3 \sqrt{3}}{3}$, which is NOT a solution to the original equation.
- For $k=2$, we get $\tan \frac {8 {\pi}}{6} = \tan \frac {4 {\pi}}{3} = \sqrt {3}$.  This is the other correct angle.

Thus, we would have to put a restriction on the values of $k$ (in this case, $k$ must be even) to yield the correct angles and avoid extraneous ones.

For $(2)$ (the conventional answer),

- For $k=0$ we get $\pi \over 3$, the correct angle.
- For $k=1$ we get $4 \pi \over 3$, the other correct angle.

Thus, for each $k$ we *only* get $\sqrt {3}$ as the answer and no others as the solution is written for all $k$.

Comment: I didn’t realize the question was asking for all solutions.  $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Means k has to be an even integer and not for all.    I hope I understood that correct.  Nice catch!!

Comment: Yes, for the book's solution, $k$ has to be restricted to the even integers in order to yield $\sqrt {3}$.  The conventional solution avoids those extraneous roots.